# if rebirth/reincarnation is true then what is your first birth/incarnation?

Tags: rebirth, reincarnation

I think the question is clear so no further explanation is needed.

Comment: Question closed due to being primarily opinion-based and too subjective in nature. Please see [*"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the Help Center.

Comment: this question falls under "Acinteyya" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acinteyya ,

Comment: @Lanka I think this question should be reopened. The Tibetan Buddhist answer to this is specific, and I believe the other schools of Buddhism are in agreement that there is no first cause, no first birth.

Comment: actually I think it is a duplicate of http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9973/first-life-in-samsara/14660#14660

Comment: @Hellyale. I will reopen the question as I see it has gained upvotes and that 3 users have submitted reopen-votes. I still think the question is lacking content and is too subjective in nature. Lets see what happens from here.

Answer (score 3):

Do you think someone might have asked that question before?

According to Access to Insight, [many of the suttas](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/search_results.html?cx=015061908441090246348%3Adj4lxnh4dda&cof=FORID%3A9%3BNB%3A1&ie=UTF-8&q=inconstruable&sa=Search&siteurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.accesstoinsight.org%2F) include the following quote,

> At Savatthi. There the Blessed One said:
>
> > "From an inconstruable beginning comes transmigration. A beginning point is not evident, though beings hindered by ignorance and fettered by craving are transmigrating & wandering on.

In other words the "first" is not evident (or, I'd read that as, it's not evident that there is a first).